# BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql

After moving my site to a new server
I got this error
With me root

```
----
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1055

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'xxx_xxx.ts_emaillist.e_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT * FROM `ts_emaillist` GROUP BY `e_email`

Filename: models/DatabaseModel.php

Line Number: 89
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).